# What tool can I use to create a partition table on a disk image (.dmg)?

Tags: terminal, partition, disk-image

I am trying to port an operating system development project to macOS. The problem here is that the project uses a tool called `parted` which is only available on linux, not macOS.

The parted tool allows you to create a partition table on a disk image (.dmg). Add/Remove partitions and format that partition to types such as Master Boot Record.

My goal is to find a macOS tool that is able to do the following:

1. Create partition table on an image
2. Create a new partition
3. Format that partition to be a Master Boot Record

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual goal is here. You've told us what you think you need to do, but that feels a lot like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) I think you need to ask us about what you're trying to achieve rather than what you think you need to do to achieve it. For instance… why an .img file? Macs use .dmg natively, which can be formatted pretty much any way you want from the GUI [or Terminal if you must].

Comment: My goal here is to create partition table on an image, make a new partition, and format that partition to be bootable. Dmg files are used for installing things while img files are used for mounting and running an operating system.

Comment: You can't boot a Mac from any image file. Making a .dmg in any format is trivial, but that seems to be an intermediate step towards your goal. If we knew your goal, there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: I am not gonna boot my Mac using that file. I will be running it in an emulator. I said before my goal is to be able to partition a .img disk image file.

Comment: I give up. Macs just don't deal in .img files natively & haven't in 20 years, they're an OS 9 format. You can make a .dmg, see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dskutl11888/mac then either convert it with `hdiutil convert (dmgfilename).dmg -format Rdxx -o (imgfilename).img` or use [DropDMG](https://c-command.com/dropdmg/) Still, if we *knew what you are trying to achieve*, there might be a much simpler way to achieve it.

Comment: Ok I'll use dmg files. I already explained what I am trying to achieve, I want to be able to create a partition table on a dmg file, create a new partition and formate it into a master boot record. Also it will have a fat/ext2 file system.

Comment: Is this disk image only used within your OS dev project (and only accessed from there)? If yes, you can create an image file in whatever format you need (but without relying on any tools macOS provides). OTOH if you want to be able to access the disk image from Finder etc, use DiskUtil to create one.

Comment: Yes this image file is only used with the OS dev project and can only be accessed from there. The problem is that there are no tools I can find that is able to do this on macOS. I am asking if there is a tool that is able to do something like this.

Comment: macOS only knows about DMGs, we don't know whether your OS dev project can handle DMGs. How does it access the image file: is this some internal library, a 3rd party library or does it rely on the OS for this?

Comment: It is able to handle dmg files, I built a dmg on linux and it ran on the emulator

Comment: @WonixerA Just to let you know: This discussion here is completely off a side track. Forget about DMGs - they do not have a place here. Tetsujin is talking about a completely different type of image file than you are (in regards to the OS 9 comment). You have completely misunderstood each other.

Comment: @WonixerA What you want is just a raw image file - i.e. a byte for byte copy of what would have been on a regular disk. It is perfectly possible to create and manage those files on macOS - as they in essence require no specific tooling as it's not really a specific format as such.

Answer (score 1):

The tools of choice are `hdiutil` and `diskutil`. Check the respective man pages for details on how to accomplish the tasks you want to accomplish. Basically

```
hdiutil create -volname DISK -size 32m -fs FAT32 disk.img
```

will create a 32m FAT32 image.

Comment: I am not asking on how to create an image. I am asking on how I can partition an existing image and make it bootable

Comment: @WonixerA hdiutil creates an image and a partion, partioning afterwards will destroy all data. How did you create an image without an MBR and without a partition table? Somehow we seem to lack a lot of detail here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the other responses consider this an "XY problem".

Disk Utility lets you create a new disk image (with MBR and MS-DOS) -- but it doesn't let you create/delete partitions the way it does for Apple disks.

You can create an initial single-partition disk image using the Disk Utility > File > New Image > Blank Image...     (or hdiutil).

You may need to double-click on the resulting .dmg   (or "attach" it using hdiutil).

`diskutil list` will list which disk images MacOS is aware of.

`diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk4 2 MBR MS-DOS BOOT 100M MS-DOS NAME R`

will repartition the disk (creating TWO partitions named BOOT and NAME). The first is 100 MB, the second uses the "REST" of the available space.

See `man diskutil` for how to use the "partitionDisk" verb.

Comment: The OP wants to create a disk *image* not work on actual disks.

Comment: @Allan Why does this not apply to disk images?

Comment: @grg the answer  here references physical disks not the image.

Comment: ? this *does* use a disk image. Not a physical disk.

Comment: @Allan `diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk4` doesn't really care what the backing store for /dev/disk4 is -- i.e. whether it's a physical disk or an attached disk image. But note that you do have to attach the image first (with something like `hdiutil attach -nomount /path/to/image.dmg`), which is what creates the /dev/disk* entry.

Comment: You and I both know that @GordonDavisson, but I’m putting myself in the shoes of a novice who is trying to figure that out for themselves.  I’m not saying this answer is wrong, but it should at least stay consistent with the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Terminal, here's a relatively simple guide:

Start by creating a "blank file" of the size you want - for example 1 GB:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=image.img bs=1024 count=1M
```

Now you want to take that file and make it accessible as if it were a real disk (similar to loop-back mounts on Linux):

```
hdiutil attach image.img -nomount
```

We're using "nomount" as we have essentially a blank disk with filesystems to mount. The output of the above command will be the device node that the file is now accessible through - for example:

```
/dev/disk4
```

It is very important to note this particular device node and use that in the following commands.

**DO NOT JUST COPY THE FOLLOWING COMMANDS WITHOUT UPDATING THE DEVICE NAME**

Now you can create a new MBR partition table on the virtual disk like this:

```
fdisk -i /dev/disk4
```

You can specify specific default templates for how you want the disk initialised by adding the `-a` flag. For example `-a dos` would create a single DOS partition on the drive.

Afterwards you can run fdisk interactively in order to remove and add partitions as you like:

```
fdisk -e /dev/disk4
```

Use for example the command `edit 1` to edit the first primary partition. You can use the `help` command to get more information.

Note that if you do not absolutely need MBR (which could very well be a requirement for a simple OS development project), you would probably be better of with a GPT partion table, which you can create using the `gpt` program instead.

After you have created your partitions, you can see their corresponding disk nodes using `diskutil` like this:

```
diskutil list
```

If you have used the "DOS" template above and the main disk device node was `/dev/disk4`, you would find the first partition available as `/dev/disk4s1`.

Now you can format the partition using the file system you want.

When you're done working with the image file, you'll want to detach it like this:

```
hdiutil detach /dev/disk4
```

Now the image file is ready to be used for whatever purpose inside a virtual machine for example.